# How to create thumbnail for video,audio which is selected from SD Card?

Tags: android

I have got the uri of the video from SD card , by using this I want to create thumbail using 
this URI .

How to achieve this?
Any one help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the thumbnail images of your Images from sdcard try this link [Thumbnail/image cache files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428735/thumbnail-image-cache-files/7428813#7428813)

Answer (score 0):

To create a Bitmap for Video

```
'ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Videofilepath,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);'
```

To create a Bitmap for Image

```
'Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath), THUMBSIZE_HEIGHT, THUMBSIZE_WIDTH);'
```